# Apply a filter on some specific points in openCV

Tags: python, opencv, imagefilter

In OpenCV Library, filers are applied on all the image which costs time and CPU load when you need a specific result on a high resolution image.

Is there a method to apply it only on some specific points (contours for example)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply it on rectangular region like this:

```
img = cv2.imread('some_image.jpg')
roi_of_img = img[col:col+width,row:row+height]
```

then apply what you want on `roi_of_img`

if you want to apply it on contour, you have two options:

1. deal with it as rectangle (found the bounding rect of the contour as follow:

   col, row, width, height = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
2. Deal with the rectangle bounding box and then apply bitwise and mask between the area inside the contour and the result of the ROI

Comment: So I understand that there are no implemented direct method. Thanks for the ideas